# why i am not able to use FirebaseDatabase in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTBmD.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnYeS.png)

my problem is when i want to use FirebaseDatabase ; android studio Cannot resolve symbol 'DatabaseReference'

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

you can try clean Project (Build-> Clean Project) or Invalidate Caches(File->Invalidate Caches -> Invalidate and Restart)

Answer (score 0):

Please  check if you have these dependencies in your `build.gradle` (Module:app) file.

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.5'
 implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.2.1')
```

For further guide on how to setup firebase properly please visit [this.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)